# How can I add an eventListener to an image inside of an external js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, external, imagesloaded

I have an index file that appends an external javascript file (a file generated from a game creator). I am trying to check if the images inside that javascript file are loaded so that I can remove the preloader by adding the class ".loaded" to the body. I cannot find a function that allows me to do this. I've tried .load, onLoad, document.ready, etc. I thought window.onload only executed after all dependent resources were also loaded (the images) but it is firing after the appended javascript file is loaded but before the images have.

Sample code:

```
<body>
<!---PreLoader--->
<div id="loader-wrapper">
    <div id="loader"></div>
</div>
<div id="content">
  (Modernizer code here that appends the js file, using function below)
  jQuery(function () {
   $('body').append("<script src='" + widgetName + ".js'></script>");
  }
</div>
```

One option I tried that fired before images:

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').addClass('loaded');
   });`

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: ready fires when the dom is ready. Load fires when the page has loaded and the images (that were included) are fully loaded.

Comment: I had a problem with that too - I found this:                                              Caveats of the load event when used with images
http://api.jquery.com/load-event/